# Mapping the relationship between 2 classes in JPA

Tags: jpa

I have a class called Contest that has an attribute called homeTeam (which is of type Team). In the Team class, there is an attribute that is an arraylist of type Contest. I'm trying to use jpa to map the relationship, and I'm thinking that because a Contest has one homeTeam, that I should use the @OneToOne annotation on the homeTeam attribute, and in the Team class, I should use the @OneToMany attribute on the ArrayList of contests, but that doesn't seem to make sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship is many-to-one, you should definitely use the most fitting annotations.
In your case `@OneToMany` for your `ArrayList` and `@ManyToOne` for your `Contest homeTeam` attribute.